# Adjusted R^2 for regression with dummy variables

Tags: regression, r-squared

I'm familiar with R^2 and adj R^2 for penalizing the addition of predictive variables in a regression.

I just want to double check that If I have three continuous predictor variables and 30 dummy variables to reflect 31 categories of the data how I should be using the equation below

```
adj R^2 = 1-(1-r^2)((n-1)/(n-k+1))
```

where

n is my number of samples

```
n = 1056
```

and s is my number of variables

```
s = 3 + 30
```

thanks

Comment: I have checked on google, just can't find anything specifically dealing with how to handle dummy variables in the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose one degree of freedom for every variable. The formula does not know, nor care, whether that variable has many values or just two (a dummy). If there are collinearities in the model matrix then that means you just take account of the ones actually used although you have other issues to deal with then anyway.